# What type of Hopf bifurcation takes place here?

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, bifurcation

#### Consider the system:

$\dot{x} = \mu x-y-xy^2-x^3$

$\dot{y} = x+\mu y - x^2y-y^3$

I have shown that a Hopf bifurcaiton takes place at the origin $(0,0)$ as a stable spiral becomes an unstable spiral as $\mu$ passes through $0$. **However I am not sure how to  classify its type**.

I have converted the system into polar coordinates and found $\dot{r} = \mu r -r^3\cos^4\theta-r^3\sin^4\theta$.

If $\theta = \pi/4$ then the system has a stable limit cycle, but this is the minimum $r$ can grow.

I dont think this classifies it as a super critical bifurcation through...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that you have correctly converted equation because $\dot{(x^2+y^2)} =2 x \dot{x} + 2 y \dot{y} = 2 (x^2+y^2) (\mu - (x^2+y^2))$ and there's no dependence on $\theta$.

Comment: we need $\dot{r}$

Comment: So what? My expression transforms to $2 r \dot{r} = 2r^2 (\mu - r^2)$ and then to $\dot{r} = r (\mu - r^2)$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I made a careless error. Thanks man :)

Comment: So would I be correct in assuming this is supercritical?

Comment: Comparing with picture at http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation I would agree with you and say that it's supercritical form.